# Is there a way to merge web.config profile properties with an external config file?

Tags: c#, web-config

I have a situation where my web.config has some properties in the profile section

```
<profile>
...
  <properties  >
        <clear/>
        <add   type="System.String" name="propData"/>
        ...
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Now I want to add some other properties but from an external file (preserving current web.config for server settings, but deploying the external config file per build).
Is there a way to merge the properties from the external file into my web.config so that I get

```
<profile>
...
  <properties  >
        <clear/>
        <add   type="System.String" name="propData"/>
        ...
        <add type="System.String" name="externalProp"/>
        ... 
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Can I do this using some web.config syntax like "configSource" or "file"?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the web.config with required additional configurations from external config,

`Example`

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
configuration.Save();
```

[Programmatically manipulating web.config](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=102)